# No error when the string constant exceeds the array size

Tags: c

I tried the code below expecting a compilation warning or error since a string is completed with a nul character in the memory, the code was compiled and the string was printed correctly. If I add a new character to the initialisation, I get an compilation warning. Any clarification please? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   char greeting[6] ="123456";
   printf("Greeting message: %s\n", greeting );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"If I add a new character to the initialisation"* - You mind clarifying that by showing what it actually *means* in your sample. I.e. you included what (seemingly) didn't do what you expected; why not also include what (seemingly) *does* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, please read my response below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization is legal C.  According to 6.7.9 (14) of the C17 standard (N2176 draft):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF–8 string literal,
> optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
> character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

So when you code this, it's assumed that you literally want the 6 characters `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'}` and no terminating null.  This is sometimes useful if you are not really going to be using the array as a string, but just want a more concise way to initialize it.

(Of course, the subsequent attempt to pass `greeting` to `printf` as if it were null terminated is *not* legal C; it is undefined behavior.  If it appears to work, it is only by chance, likely that the next byte in memory just happened to be 0 at the time.)

If you want to be certain the null byte is included, you can write

```
char greeting[6] ="123456\0";
```

This yields a warning.  Or, of course, you can let the compiler figure out the array size for you, and just write

```
char greeting[] = "123456";
```

in which case the terminating null is guaranteed, and the array will have size 7.

Comment: @Schwern: I'm looking at the N2176 draft, and it's 6.7.9(14) here.  Maybe the numbering changed in the final standard.

Comment: I only have the N1362 draft. I guess the numbers did drift.

Answer (score 2):

> If the size of the array is known, it may be one less than the size of the string literal, in which case the terminating null character is ignored.

`char greeting[7] ="123456";` produces the array `{'1','2','3','4','5','6',0}`. Note the trailing null byte.

`char greeting[6] ="123456";` produces the array `{'1','2','3','4','5','6'}`, no null byte.

`printf("Greeting message: %s\n", greeting );` happens to work because the following memory happens to be zero'd. It could be anything.

Here's an example which, in my particular instance, demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char foo[] = "abcd";
   char greeting[4] ="1234";

   printf("foo = %p, greeting = %p\n", foo, greeting);
   printf("%s\n", greeting);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is...

```
foo = 0x7ffee6c37427, greeting = 0x7ffee6c37423
1234abcd
```

Here we see that `foo` is in the memory immediately after `greeting`. When `printf` reads `greeting` it dutifully reads until the first null byte which is at the end of the `foo`.

```
greeting
|
v
1234abcd\0
    ^
    |
    foo
```

So unless you really need to allocate more memory than the initializing string, use `greeting[] = "123456"` to make sure you have a null byte.